# Why is there no Ubuntu One sync in my tomboy notes sync preferences?

Tags: 10.04, ubuntu-one, sync, tomboy

I started using Tomboy on two other computers with 10.10 and 11.04 beta and am starting to like it.  When I went to set up sync on my 10.04 box, I see that there isn't even an option to sync to Ubuntu One.  What do I need to do to get that option to show up in the sync preferences?

Answer (score 2):

Must be in the version included in 10.04, the one click add sync wasn't there. It was just about that easy using the method found in the tutorial at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne/Tutorials/Notes